# Calculation using pointers in C

Tags: c

I have an assignment in which I have to calculate with some numbers, some hidden behind pointers, I think.

I have a list of objects (game characters in this case), that have attack and defense values. My job is to sum all the attack values up using the following way.

First, I have my sum variable.

```
double a = 0;
```

Afterwards it will be used in a function together with the created list.

```
reduce_list(list, add_attack, &a);
```

reduce_list looks like this:

```
void reduce_list(Node* list, ReduceFun f, void* state) {
int i = 0;
for (Node* node = list; node != NULL; node = node->next, i++) {
    f(state, node->value, i);
} }
```

Last but not least, the add_attack function looks like this:

```
void add_attack(void* state, void* element, int index) {
}
```

One node of the list looks like this:

```
(value, next)
```

...so the whole list looks like

```
(value, (value, (value, (value, NULL))))
```

For the addition I use double values from objects in the list, which I get in the add_attack function so thats not the problem.

I'm just asking myself how to add them to the void pointer 'state' in add_attack. If I change it somehow, I change the a variable right? My goal is to have the sum of the doubles I get from the  elements in the list.

May anyone help me with this? I have no idea, what to do in this situation...

Comment: Why is it a `void*` and not a `double*`? Or why not just make the function return the result instead of using an out parameter (assuming your assignment doesn't mandate that)?

Comment: Please post the definitions. What is `Node`? What is `ReduceFun`? `.so the whole list looks like` post the datatype and a function that appends the data to the list - that way others will "know" how the list is structured.

Comment: @Blaze Probably to keep the higher-order function general so that it works on arbitrary data.

Comment: In C a `void *` is a "generic pointer", it's implicitly convertible to any other pointer type. You can easily assign a variable of type `void *` to another variable e.g. of type `double *`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: `void *` is not implicitly convertible to any other pointer type. It is implicitly convertible to any other pointer to object type.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm just asking myself how to add them to the void pointer 'state' in add_attack.

You can’t. You first need to cast the `void` pointer to your actual object. The object being passed is your `&a`, so you can cast it as follows:

```
double *d = state;
```

You’ll need to do the same for `element`. Once that’s done, you can simply add the two values and reassign the result to `*d` (you will be mutating the accumulator variable `a`).

Lastly, don’t be misled: you won’t need the parameter `index` at all. Ignore it.